# Jenkins workspace management

Tags: java, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, hudson

Jenkins uses "@" sign when creating new jenkins-pipeline workspace folders. The reason why these "@" are used is unclear for me, but I also don't need to understand how Jenkins works internally (although interesting...).

However, these "@" are causing us troubles because we are running bash commands from these workspace directories, and "@" is unfortunately not supported by some tools.

My question: is it possible to configure Jenkins so that it uses another sign than "@" for the workspace's path directories?

================

Ok, some additional research seem to mention than these "@" are used when concurrent build are possible. However, in our case, we explicitely checked the box mentioning that "no concurrent build are allowed".

(Sure we could take content of workspaces and copy them somwhere else in order to start our commands... but this can't be changed that easily ...)

Comment: Check my response on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349630/how-do-jenkins-pipeline-builds-determine-the-workspace-folder), it covers your issue. The `@` separator is hardcoded, so you either need to compile jenkins yourself or try to somehow work around these in your tooling (i.e. you are free to specify the workspace directory yourself, add some logic not containing `@`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it !!

One can start Jenkins using the following parameter: `-Dhudson.slaves.WorkspaceList=_`

See also here for a list of possible parameter: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties